Can I use a frontend framework for designing the storefront in shopify?
I'm trying to build a custom Product Page in the storefront to load the products that were created using my app.
When a product meets certain conditions then my app will render that product in that custom products page.
At 1st when I started testing I started my design using App embed blocks with HTML and CSS but I've a pretty complex design for the product page and developing it using app embeds doesn't feel like a good approach.
So I was wondering if I can use a frontend framework to design the product page of my storefront. If so then how?
Thanks!
